# How to include graphics inside a mindmap?

Tags: tikz-pgf, includegraphics, mindmaps

I am trying to include plots in eps format inside each mindmaps circle using TikZ environment but I am unable to center these graphs inside each circle. I have tried the \centering command inside the \node command but without success:

```
\node{\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{fig_5}}
```

This is what I have.
[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX-SE. Your question is quite unclear at this point. Please insert a Minimal Working Example of what you tried already and add a sketch of what you need instead of what you have. So that members here could help you out.

Comment: By default the image should be centered in the node, do you have e.g. `align=left` in the style of the nodes?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the ```align=left``` but it has no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`adjustbox` should do the trick.
The following picture shows the effect of wrapping oversized icons with
`\begin{adjustbox}{center}` and `\end{adjustbox}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fullpage,graphicx,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    mindmap,
    concept color = red!30,
    every node/.style = {concept}
]
 
\node{%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{icon1}%
}
child [grow = down] {%
  node {%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{icon1}%
  }
}
child [grow = north west] {%
  node {%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{icon1}%
  }%
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\qquad
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    mindmap,
    concept color = red!30,
    every node/.style = {concept}
]
 
\node{%
  \begin{adjustbox}{center}%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{icon1}%
  \end{adjustbox}%
}
child [grow = down] {%
  node {%
    \begin{adjustbox}{center}%
      \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{icon1}%
    \end{adjustbox}%      
  }
}
child [grow = north west] {
  node {%
    \begin{adjustbox}{center}%    
      \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{icon1}%
    \end{adjustbox}%      
  }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very beautiful output :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, good to know you like it. :-)

Comment: @citsahcots, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pablo, you are welcome!